# Angular how to minimum 8 characters including 1 uppercase 1 lowercase 1 number 1 special character using validation

Tags: html, angular, regex, angular-validation

i want it to show on my html element using ngif minimum 8 characters including 1 uppercase 1 lowercase 1 number 1 special character

**register.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" novalidate>
  <label for="pNumber" class="text-primary">PASSWORD*</label>
  <input type="text" id="passWord" class="form-control form-rounded" placeholder="Ilagay ang Password"
    formControlName="passWord" #passWord />
  <ul *ngIf="registerForm.get('passWord')?.errors?.['pattern']">
    <li class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('passWord')?.hasError('has8Letter')">
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; At
      least 8 characters
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="registerForm.get('passWord')?.hasError('hasCapitalCase')">
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; At
      least 1 Capital Letter and 1 Small Letter
    </li>
    <li class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('passWord')?.hasError('hasNumber')">
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; At
      least 1 Number
    </li>
    <li class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('passWord')?.hasError('hasSpecialCharacter')">
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; At
      least 1 non-alphanumeric character
    </li>
    <li class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerForm.get('passwordMatch')?.hasError('passwordMismatch')">
      <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;
      Password is Match
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**register.component.ts**

```
registerForm!:FormGroup
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder ){
    let hasNumber = /\d/
    let hasCapitalCase = /[A-Z][a-z]/

    let hasSpecialCharacter = /[ [!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"|,.<>/
    let has8Letter = /.{8,}/
    this.registerForm = new FormGroup({
      phoneNumber: new FormControl(null,[
        Validators.required,
       
      ]),
      passWord :new FormControl(null , Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(hasNumber),
        Validators.pattern(hasCapitalCase),
        Validators.pattern(hasSpecialCharacter),
        Validators.pattern(has8Letter),
       // Validators.pattern(/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{8}$/)
      ])),
      passwordMatch: fb.control(null,[
      Validators.required,
     
      ]),
      email:fb.control(null,[
        Validators.required
      ]),
      designation:fb.control(null,[
        Validators.required
      ]),
      fName:fb.control(null ,[Validators.required]),
      mName:fb.control(null ,[Validators.required]),
      lName:fb.control(null ,[Validators.required]),
      sName:fb.control(null ,[Validators.required]),
      birthday:fb.control(null ,[Validators.required]),
      province:fb.control(null ,[Validators.required]),
      city:fb.control(null ,[Validators.required]),
      barangay:fb.control(null ,[Validators.required]),
    }),
    {
      validators: this.passwordMatchValidator // Add any other validators as necessary
    }
  }
  passwordMatchValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const password = control.get('passWord')?.value;
    const confirmPassword = control.get('passwordMatch')?.value;
  
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      control.get('passwordMatch')?.setErrors({ passwordMismatch: true });
    } else {
      control.get('passwordMatch')?.setErrors(null);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Expected as per below**

[image: im expecting like this]

Comment: Please. reconsider what you are foisting on your users.

This is a truly horrible requirement for a password, does very little for producing a "good" password, and is just annoying and inconvenient for the user.

The US National Institute of Standards and Technology has for several years now, recommended that you focus on password length instead of complexity.

You'd be much better off dropping the "one of each" requirement and bumping your minimum length up to say, 12 characters.

See for example, https://www.auditboard.com/blog/nist-password-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Pls take a look, I added such solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/validator-formgroup-multi-pattern-scxyuf
[image: strong text]

How to achieve it:

```
 private regexValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
  return control?.value && regex.test(control.value) ? null : error;
};
```

}

Next method is used just to show that those errors are 'registered' in FormControl error field.

```
 getErrorKeys(controlName) {
  return Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls[controlName].errors);
 }
```

Usage:

```
 Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      this.regexValidator(new RegExp(/.{8,}/), {
        min8Chars: true,
      }),
      this.regexValidator(this.hasSpecialCharacter, {
        missSpecialCharacter: true,
      })])
```